# Python process can't create a file in a directory, keeps getting `permission denied` IOError

Tags: permissions, python, setuid, uid

I've a directory `mnt` with 777 permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root    root   14336 Feb  5 15:52 mnt
```

I've created a bunch of users in the group `root` from uid to `5204` to `5250`.

I've a python script that launches a bunch of processes which:

- Change the uid to one of those I created earlier
- Create a file under `mnt` directory

but I keep getting `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`. What am I missing?

Here's the python script I am using:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import random
import time
import os

def test_function(name, uid):
      os.setuid(uid)
      fname = "/home/username/mnt/file-%s-%d" % (name, random.randrange(100))
      print "Will open file: %s\n" % fname
      file = open(fname, 'w+')
      file.close

processes = []

for m in range(5204, 5212):
       name = 'Thread-%s' % str(m)
       p = Process(target=test_function, args=(name, m))
       p.start()
       processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
       p.join()
```

Note: I run this python script with root permissions and `mnt` is an NFS directory mounted with Amazon EFS

Comment: Are you sure it's the file creation that is causing the error, and not the call to `os.setuid(uid)`?

Comment: @JohanMyréen yes, I verified that setuid is definitely successful

Comment: can you add the contents of `print (os.environ)` ?

Comment: {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'USERNAME': 'root', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'SUDO_COMMAND': '/usr/bin/python testscript.py', 'HOSTNAME': 'ip-10-1-21-120', 'SUDO_UID': '1311883', 'SUDO_GID': '100', 'HISTSIZE': '1000', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'USER': 'root', 'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin', 'MAIL': '/var/spool/mail/username', 'SUDO_USER': 'username'}

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve [mcve]? In most cases, just creating [mcve], and thus sorting out the chaff, will point you at the root-cause of your issue. If not, post the [mcve] here, as it'd be easier to help you with it.